# Explain how it's possible to allocate and free memory for a 2d array in C with just these 2 lines:

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int (*mapTerrain)[10] = (int (*)[10])malloc(sizeof(int[10][10]));
free(mapTerrain);
```

Someone on this site suggested these 2 lines for working with dynamical 2d arrays in C. Dimensions are `[10][10]`. Problem is, I'm not sure I understand them correctly. If I had to explain these 2 lines I'd say the following:

On the left we have an array of `int` pointers with size 10. (Can't explain the casting, I myself would expect it to be `int *`).

What's being passed to `malloc` is an array of `int`-s sized `[10][10]`. (Why isn't it ...`malloc(sizeof(int*10*10));`?) What allows us to pass an array to `malloc` instead of `size_t size`?

As for the `free(mapTerrain);` line. How come one `free` is enough? From what I remember you have to call `free` for every row of a dynamical 2d array.

Comment: `int (*p)[10]` is not an array of `int*`, it's a pointer to a `int[10]`. (The first would be `int* p[10]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast of the result of `malloc` is just clutter and not necessary.

The most correct, formal version would be:

```
int (*mapTerrain)[10][10] = malloc(sizeof(int[10][10]));
```

This is an array pointer to a `int [10][10]` array. However, such a pointer is a bit painful to work with in practice, since to get an item we have to do:

- `*mapTerrain` to get the array pointed at from the array pointer.
- `(*mapTerrain)` parenthesis to not trip over operator precedence.
- `(*mapTerrain)[i][j]` to get a single item.

As a trick, we can instead use a pointer to the first element of the `int[10][10]`. The first element is of type `int[10]`, and so an array pointer to that element is `int(*)[10]`. With this type, we can do `mapTerrain[i][j]` as expected, because `i` means "give me array number `i`" through pointer arithmetic.

This trick is essentially the same thing as when we do something like

```
char* ptp = malloc(sizeof("hello"));`
```

Here we don't point to the whole array either, we point at the first element of it.

---

`sizeof(int[10][10])` is 100% equivalent to `sizeof(int*10*10)` (or `400` for that matter), but the first is self-documenting code, showing that we are expecting to use the allocated data as an array `int[10][10]`.

---

One free is enough because there is just one malloc. You allocate the whole 2D array as a contiguous chunk of memory.

Further reading: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up almost everything. Only thing still unclear is the casting however. I'm working in Visual Studio, where it's required.

Comment: @Oleg - The casting is required if you compile your C code as C++. Generally not a good idea..